# Does xlc in AIX 5 support c++ abi?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, aix

Does xlc in AIX 5 support c++ abi?

Comment: Your comments below suggest that you don't know precisely what "C++ ABI" means. Every C++ compiler has a C++ ABI, but not all have the same. Some C++ compilers have a header `<cxxabi.h>` which describes their ABI, but not all.

Comment: there is a /usr/local/include/c++/3.3.2/cxxabi.h in my AIX machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In between versions of xlc, the C++ ABI is fairly stable.  Mixing C++ objects compiled between GCC and xlc may have undefined results.

Comment: thank you. and how to compile it with xlc? when I add cxxabi.h there is an error:xlC_r -g -qtbtable=full -qlist bt.cpp -DAIX -bdynamic -lptools_ptr -o bt 
"bt.cpp", line 12.10: 1540-0836 (S) The #include file <cxxabi.h> is not found.

Comment: AFAIK, cxxabi.h is part of libstdc++.   Perhaps installing from the Linux toolbox may include it.

Comment: Stup: this file is in /usr/local/include/c++/3.3.2/; and if I add -I /usr/local/include/c++/3.3.2/ to the xlC_r; I got this error:"/usr/local/include/c++/3.3.2/bits/basic_string.h", line 45.10: 1540-0836 (S) The #include file <bits/atomicity.h> is not found.
"/usr/local/include/c++/3.3.2/bits/concept_check.h", line 40.10: 1540-0836 (S) The #include file <bits/c++config.h> is not found......

Comment: That portion may be in in the libstdc++-devel package, if you're using the Linux toolbox for AIX.

Comment: Also note that I'm not sure if libstdc++ is compatible with the native compilers.   I'd hazzard to say that they are gcc/g++ specific.